# Why do Yuko's poems always end in 'Mogami River'?

Tags: nichijou

Several times during the anime, Yūko Aioi ends her short haikus with 'Mogami River'.

I've read on the [Wikipedia page for Mogami River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogami_River#cite_note-2) that Matsuo Bashō used it in at least one of his poems, but I can't much written about it, so it seems to me to be not a well-known feature of his poems.

Is this the correct reason for the inclusion of the line, or is there an alternative reason?

[image]

(I couldn't find an image with subtitles, so hopefully this is a correct example)

Comment: Matsuo Basho [wrote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokku) several [hokku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokku) as he traveled along the Mogami River (Mogamigawa) in the 15th century. It's not a feature of his poems, but rather the subject of them (it's a lovely boat ride).

Comment: It's a lot easier to do 5-7-5 and reference nature when you have a final line of length 5 (mo+ga+mi+ga+wa) that you stick in to every poem because Yuuko can't think of a whole haiku (was my takeaway).

Comment: @MarkS. I guess you could post that as an answer, since it looks legit for a comedy series.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this academic site](http://haikutopics.blogspot.com/2006/05/river-kawa.html), while it is not a kigo (season word), the mogami river is well known in Japanese haiku.

I imagine Yuuko has trouble thinking of an entire 5-7-5 poem, and so she just reuses this famous line for that reason.